# 2x2 Matrix vector product in C# with SIMD

Tags: c#, simd

I am making something where I want to multiply the same 2x2 `short` valued matrix with different 2-dimensional `short` valued vectors a lot of times per second, and performance is important in this case. Right now, I'm just doing it the naive way and writing out the matrix multiplication. I looked up the SIMD capabilities of C#, and found that there is no way to make a 2x2 matrix of this type. So I tried to do it with the `Vector<T>` struct from `System.Numerics.Vectors`. The constructor expected at least 4 elements to go into the vector though. I could work around it and make it work with 4-dimensional vectors, but I was wondering if there was a  way to do what I wanted to do easier: multiply a 2x2 matrix with a 2-dimensional vector into a new 2-dimensional vector with SIMD.

Comment: Are you able to use the SIMD instrinsics from `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86`?

Comment: @harold would those work on any system? From the Microsoft docs it looks like they would only work on Intel processors

Comment: It will work on both Intel and AMD processor, if that's what you mean. Not ARM though.

Answer (score 5):

Using `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86`, [`Sse2.MultiplyAddAdjacent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse2.multiplyaddadjacent?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Intrinsics_X86_Sse2_MultiplyAddAdjacent_System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector128_System_Int16__System_Runtime_Intrinsics_Vector128_System_Int16__) can be used to do the heavy lifting, with some shuffling etc to line up the data. For example:

```
struct Vec2
{
    public short X, Y;
}

struct Mat2x2
{
    public short A, B, C, D;
}

static unsafe Vec2 Mul(Mat2x2 m, Vec2 v)
{
    // movd: 0 0 0 0 0 0 Y X
    var rawvec = Sse2.LoadScalarVector128((int*)&v);
    // pshufd: Y X Y X Y X Y X
    var vec = Sse2.Shuffle(rawvec, 0).AsInt16();
    // movq: 0 0 0 0 D C B A
    var mat = Sse2.LoadScalarVector128((ulong*)&m).AsInt16();
    // pmaddwd: 0 0 DY+CX BY+AX
    var dword_res = Sse2.MultiplyAddAdjacent(mat, vec);
    // packssdw: 0 0 DY+CX BY+AX 0 0 DY+CX BY+AX
    var rawres = Sse2.PackSignedSaturate(dword_res, dword_res);
    Vec2 res;
    *((int*)&res) = Sse2.ConvertToInt32(rawres.AsInt32());
    return res;
}
```

The resulting assembly is fairly reasonable:

```
 mov         dword ptr [rsp+10h],ecx  
 mov         qword ptr [rsp+18h],rdx  
 vmovd       xmm0,dword ptr [rsp+18h]  
 vpshufd     xmm0,xmm0,0  
 vmovq       xmm1,mmword ptr [rsp+10h]  
 vpmaddwd    xmm0,xmm1,xmm0  
 vpackssdw   xmm0,xmm0,xmm0  
 vmovd       eax,xmm0  
 mov         dword ptr [rsp],eax
 mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp]
```

But it's not ideal. The `m` and `v` function arguments (and the result at the end) are both "bounced through" memory .. which admittedly is exactly what the C# code said to do. That can be worked around by manually combining `X` and `Y` into an `int` with arithmetic and then using `ConvertScalarToVector128Int32`, but then the JIT is apparently not smart enough to see that the arithmetic is redundant. So there seems to be no good solution. Hopefully at some point the JIT optimizer will be able to detect such pointless "bounce through memory" situations and remove them.

An other point is that the `MultiplyAddAdjacent` is partly wasted: it does 8 products, but only 4 are a useful computation, the upper half of the vector is just zeroes. If you had 2 vectors to multiply by the same 2x2 matrix, that could be done at a small extra cost, much less than simply calling the above function twice.

Comment: Also disappointing that compiling with AVX enabled didn't use `vbroadcastss` instead of `vmovd` + `vpshufd`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, that could be done manually with `vec = Avx.BroadcastScalarToVector128((float*)&v).AsInt16();` (the bounce through memory is still incurred)